# ReviewBoard changes Heroku Git repo URL, clone fails

Tags: git, heroku

When creating a Git repo in ReviewBoard that is hosted by Heroku, I enter the Heroku Git URL:

```
git@heroku.com:appname.git
```

ReviewBoard is changing this into:

```
ssh://git@heroku.com/appname.git
```

Heroku doesn't like that and rejects the clone attempt:

```
2012-08-22 22:26:39,267 - ERROR - Git: Failed to find valid repository ssh://git@heroku.com/appname.git: 
 !  Invalid path.
 !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

**How can I get ReviewBoard not to rewrite the Git repo URL?**

Why doesn't Heroku accept URLs of the form: `ssh://git@heroku.com/appname.git` ?
Where can I report this as a bug in Heroku? I've searched their site and can't see where to open a support ticket.

Comment: DId you enter the right address (git@heroku...) in the mirror path of your local clone declaration in the Review Board? (http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/admin/configuration/repositories/#local-clone)

Comment: Excellent. I have added an answer to close that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, one missing element was:

Enter the right address (`git@heroku...`) in the mirror path of the local clone declaration in the Review Board.

See "[Local clone sction of ReviewBoard](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/admin/configuration/repositories/#local-clone)".

> In order to work with Review Board, a local clone needs to be kept in sync regularly.
>   It should either have direct access to a central Git server, or it needs to be updated on every commit to the central Git server.
>
> The Path field should be the full path of the `.git` directory inside this checkout.
>   For example:

```
/var/git/projectname/.git
```

> The `Mirror` path` field should contain the repository URL.
>   Find the URL you should use from within a git checkout by running the following:

```
$ git remote show origin
```

> The value shown as URL: should be entered as the mirror path. For example:

```
git@git.example.com:projectname.git
```

> The `Username` and `Password` fields should be blank.